# Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).on is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm upgrading our jQuery version and have been trying to update the `.bind()` statements to `.on()` but am having issues getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).on is not a function

I think possibly it's related to the position of the brackets. I've tried a variety of ways to update based on suggestions from this site but have so far been unsuccessful.

```js
return $.getJSON(ASite.BaseURL + 'api/dashboard/gadget/content/' + this.id).then(function(data) {
  var result;
  if (this.processGadgetContent) {
    result = this.processGadgetContent(data);
  } else {
    result = data;
  }
  return result;
}.on(this)).done(function(data) {
  if (this.gadgetSummaryLoaded) {
    this.gadgetSummaryLoaded(data);
  }
}.on(this)).always(function() {
  this.isLoading(false);
}.on(this));
```

I have a lot of this type of code, if someone has any thoughts on how to update this type of script it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. You cannot call jQuery's `on()` method on a plain JS object. I'm not even sure why you'd want to do anything even remotely like that - especially in this case as `$.getJSON()` has nothing to do with `bind()`. Remove all instances of `.on(this)` and your problem should disappear.

Comment: What do you think `.on(this)` is supposed to be doing???

Comment: Code should just be
`$.getJSON(...).done(function (){...}).always(function (){...});`

Comment: It seems the bindings are for knockout.  After updating the code as suggested, I get the following errors on loading the gadgets: Bindings value: css: $parent.alertClass($data, 'tab-'), click: gadget.selectOption.bind(gadget), attr: { 'aria-selected': gadget.isAriaSelected($data) }
Message: summary.status is not a function
    at AStatusGadget.alertClass (nuim-status.js:26)
    at eval (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout-2.3.0.debug.js:2000), <anonymous>:3:54)